# How can i run another activity in Android App?

Tags: android

Thats my logcats 
When i started my application, click on the button and it must going to another activity, but that will appear initial (main) Activity(layout)
Please help me

```
11-21 17:51:04.458 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
11-21 17:51:04.778 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 17:51:04.790 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-21 17:51:20.714 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-21 17:51:21.254 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 17:51:27.414 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 17:51:28.626 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 17:51:40.166 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 17:51:42.674 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 17:51:43.370 1194-1194/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

This my first Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button upgrade_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    upgrade_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upgrade);
    upgrade_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UprgadeActivity.class));
        }
    });


    Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle1 != null) {
        boolean check = bundle1.getBoolean("checkbox");
    }


    }
```

and second Activity

```
public class BrainUpgrade extends AppCompatActivity  {


CheckBox checkbox;
boolean checkbox1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.brain_upgrade);

    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkbox1 = checkbox.isChecked();

    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
    bundle1.putBoolean("checkbox",checkbox1);
    intent.putExtras(bundle1);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

In this Activity is my button

```
public class UprgadeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.uprgade);

    Button body_upgrade;
    body_upgrade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    body_upgrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BodyUpgrade.class));
        }
    });

    Button brain_upgrade;
    brain_upgrade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.brain_upgrade);
    brain_upgrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BrainUpgrade.class));
        }
    });

}
```

My Manifest.file `

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UprgadeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_uprgade" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BodyUpgrade"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_body_upgrade" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BrainUpgrade"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brain_upgrade" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: Why don't you provide the code where you trigger the navigation to the other activity?

Comment: Paste your java code

Comment: First of all, there is no error shown on the log you have given, secondly , for the people to help you , you must provide some code so that we can point out what you are doing wrong

Comment: Paste your AndroidManifest.xml as well.

Comment: Why you start Main Activity in BrainActivity#onCreate?

Comment: provide your xml files as well. maybe all of your xml have same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that will appear initial (main) Activity(layout)

On `brain_upgrade` Button Click of your `UpgradeActivity` you are starting `BrainUpgrade` activity.

But inside onCreate of BrainUpgrade, You are starting MainActivity.

Thats why you are seeing main layout.

Comment: put your necessary conditions on starting MainActivity from BrainUpgrade actvity. Otherwise you will redirect to MainActivity from your UprgadeActivity

Comment: where do you see that ?

Comment: when you actually want to launch MainActivity from BrainUpgrade activity ?

Comment: i never want to do it

Comment: i launch a BrainActivity from UpgradeActivity

Comment: then just remove line  Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class); from BrainUpgrade activity

Comment: I think that problem in the Intent because when i delete it in the BrainActivity and in MainActivity, application work well

Comment: but when i will delete it how i can pass my boolean value between activities ?